# sql query to perform division between 2 tables and insert result into a third table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am quite the novice when it comes to sql, but when I decide to get into something I go for it all the way. I am trying to create a database that will perform calculations based on inputs for product manufacturing priorities. I have a table that is strictly inputs by product numbers and planned production for each week. In another table I have some conversion values that I need to use to convert planned footage into pounds. In a third table I will need to insert the value of the product item numbers planned footage for each week divided by the feet per pound in the conversion table and insert these values into the appropriate week number column in the third table that corresponds to the week number column in the first table.

I hope that is as clear to you as it is in my head. The problem I have is that I do not know how to make this a dynamic query that will match the column name for the week number and perform the math and insertion appropriately.

My SELECT code does not even work properly as it seems to be grabbing all of the values from every week number column and summing them up before dividing by the feet per pound value. I tried to do an insert function after this within the same call but had no luck and didn't actually expect to either. I have not gotten any farther than this yet. Any help at all to even get me started would be greatly appreciated. In the meantime I will continue to try some different things and see what I can come up with.

```
SELECT WeeklyFootagePlan.Wire_PN / Conversions.Finish_ft_lb
FROM WeeklyFootagePlan, Conversions
WHERE WeeklyFootagePlan.Wire_PN = Conversions.Wire_PN;
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your query per se.  Can you show us sample input and the output you expect to get?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what the data looks like.  Can you provide the data?  It seems that you might need to GROUP BY the week or limit the results for the week by including it in the WHERE clause.  Again, hard to say without knowing what the data looks like.

Comment: WeeklyFootagePlan table has columns with PN and Week1,Week2, etc. Conversions table has Columns with PN and feet per pound, and table 3 has columns same as WeeklyFootagePlan. So for example I need to take the value from PN 1 and Week1 of WeeklyFootagePlan and divide it by the feet per pound of Conversions table and insert the new value into table 3. Hope that helps. I do need these to be different tables in case you were going to ask why don't I put them in the same table!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to join your **WeeklyFootagePlan** table to your **Conversions** table on column **PN**.

Below is a sample Solution:

**Recreate some version of your tables**

```
create table YourSchema.WeeklyCalculation(PN int(10)
                                        , Week1Conversion double
                                        , Week2Conversion double
                                        , Week3Conversion double
                                        , primary key PN_pkey(PN));

create table YourSchema.WeeklyFootagePlan(PN int(10) auto_increment
                                        , Week1 double
                                        , Week2 double
                                        , Week3 double
                                        , primary key PN_pkey(PN));

create table YourSchema.Conversion(PN int(10)
                                 , Conversion1 double
                                 , Conversion2 double
                                 , Conversion3 double
                                 , primary key PN_pkey(PN));
```

**Insert some data**

```
insert 
  into YourSchema.WeeklyFootagePlan(Week1, Week2, Week3)
select 50, 20, 12.5;

insert 
  into YourSchema.Conversion(PN, Conversion1, Conversion2, Conversion3)
select 1, .25, 1.5, 2.5;
```

**Insert into your Third table**

```
insert
  into YourSchema.WeeklyCalculation(PN, Week1Conversion, Week2Conversion, Week3Conversion)
select w.PN, w.week1/c.Conversion3 as SomeConversion
     , w.Week2/c.Conversion3 as AnotherConversion
     , w.Week3/c.Conversion2 as YetAnotherConversion
  from YourSchema.WeeklyFootagePlan w
  join YourSchema.Conversion c
    on c.PN = w.PN;
```

**Result:**

```
select *
  from YourSchema.WeeklyCalculation;

PN | Week1Conversion | Week2Conversion | Week3 Conversion
1  |      20         |      8          |    8.33333333333333
```

Comment: I honestly don't know what you are getting at here. I copied your code exactly and changed the table names to my table names but I am getting a syntax error in the FROM clause. I copied your code exactly without changing anything and tried to save it and I get the same error. I obviously took out the extra ...... to simplify the amount of conversions I was trying to do just to test it but I can't even get the query to save because of the error. How exactly is this statement working and what is it trying to do?

Comment: There is nothing complex about the solution, I just gave you a simple example based on the data provided.  Some detail about the error you're getting and where you are saving it to would help figure out what issue you are having.  I'll add additional detail to the solution, perhaps that will make it clearer for you.